# Deriving $\beta$ from expected loss function (Hastie, Tibshirani)

Tags: machine-learning

I am looking at equation (2.16) on page 19 of [Elements of Statistical Learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/) and can't seem to be able to derive it. I used $f(x) = x^T\beta$ as the linear model, and tried calculating $\beta$ by minimizing the expected prediction error (EPE).

$$ EPE(f) = E[(Y-f(X))^2] $$
$$ EPE(f) = E[(Y-X\beta)^T(Y-X\beta)] $$

$$ \partial EPE(f)/ \partial \beta = E[X^T(Y-X\beta)] = 0 $$
$$ \partial EPE(f)/ \partial \beta = E[X^TY]-E[X^TX\beta)] = 0 $$
$$ E[X^TY] = \beta E[X^TX]  \text{  (as beta is constant)} $$
$$ \beta = [E(X^TX)]^{-1}E(X^TY) $$

Now my result is different from equation (2.16) in the book and I am clueless why is that the case. I am guessing there is a linear algebra rule I am missing. Why is my $X^T$ their $X$ and vice-versa?

Any word will help!

Comment: It looks like this question should have the tag `self-study` added.

Comment: The second transformation also caused me problems ;-) [@grand_chat helped me out at MathOverflow](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2447913/484829): $(Y-X^T\beta)^2$ is a scalar, and deriving a scalar w.r.t. a column vector $\beta$  gives a column vector because 'denominator layout' is used. Just in case anyone knows as little about matrix calculus than me. Also wrote $X^T$ because of bill_e's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using $f(x) = X^{T} \beta$.  When you write $EPE(f) = E[(Y - X \beta)^{T}(Y - X\beta)]$ you are off by just a transpose on X.

You should write instead:

$$ 
EPE(f) = E[(Y - X^{T} \beta)^{T}(Y - X^{T} \beta)]
$$

in accordance with your original linear model, $f(x) = X^{T} \beta$.  Just a small mistake.

Comment: Are you sure? If you look at the derivation from equation (2.3), the authors do begin from $f(x)= X^T\beta$ but write their matrix form as $(Y−X\beta)$T(Y−X\beta)$ equation (2.4). I was trying to follow their notation throughout.

Comment: They use that notation to get to equation 2.6 which is what you have.  You did it right!  You just need to pay attention to how they defined X, and x_{i}.  Check the last half of section 2.2 (at least in my version) where they talk about their notation conventions.  An easy self check with matrix algebra is just to keep track of the matrix dimensions.  The number of columns of A must equal the number of rows of B in A*B.

Comment: You are correct, there seems to be different usage of notation in the two cases. Thanks!

Comment: Well, there seems no other logical answer to it. If $X$ were an orthogonal matrix, there would be no doubt. Still seems strange to me that they would bring in different notations into a related section. Their statement, "The least squares solution (2.6) amounts to replacing the expectation in (2.16) by averages over the training data.", cannot be true unless we interchange the notations.

Comment: There is a reason to change notations.  Most of the algorithms discussed in that book aren't linear regression, and so don't need a design matrix.  It is simpler to just call both y and x row vectors and then write x^T when you need x to be a column vector for linear regression.  For nearest neighbors or decision tree etc. it muddles up the prose to keep x defined as a column vector while y is a row vector (or visa versa, I can't remember for sure).

Comment: They explained this notation while discussing linear models, but must have explained this change in more detail. It gets confusing as I proceed.

Comment: Well feel free to ask more Q's